# How to build OpenSSL on Windows with Visual Studio 2017?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, build, openssl

I am trying to use OpenSSL but I am stuck on the step of compiling. The OpenSSL project has very unfriendly (bad) documentation.

Is there any actual help how to build the latest OpenSSL version on Windows with Visual Studio 2017?

I didn't find any helpful information on the official OpenSSL site. Yes, there are a lot of posts on the Internet about OpenSSL compilation, but all of them are obsolete.

Comment: Have you considered using [pre-compiled OpenSSL binaries](https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Binaries) instead of compiling it yourself?

Comment: Did you read the INSTALL file?
 This provides instructions for how to build OpenSSL. https://github.com/openssl/openssl/blob/OpenSSL_1_1_0-stable/INSTALL. You should also read NOTES.WIN for Windows specific information: https://github.com/openssl/openssl/blob/OpenSSL_1_1_0-stable/NOTES.WIN

Comment: You should ask a specific question for a particular problem. Since Stack Overflow hides the Close reason from you: *"Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it."* Regarding *"... there are a lot of posts on the Internet ... but all of them are obsolete"* - I doubt it.

Answer (score 66, accepted):

I've not used VS2017 but previous versions. I imagine it is much the same. Note the instructions below are for OpenSSL 1.1.0 or above. They do not work for OpenSSL 1.0.2. In brief the steps are:

1. Install Perl (either ActiveState or Strawberry)

[EDIT, see my (kritzel_sw) comment below: I would strongly recommend to use Strawberry)]

2. Install NASM
3. Make sure both Perl and NASM are on your %PATH%
4. Fire up a Visual Studio Developer Command Prompt with administrative privileges (make sure you use the 32-bit one if you are building 32-bit OpenSSL, or the 64-bit one if you are building 64-bit OpenSSL)
5. From the root of the OpenSSL source directory enter `perl Configure VC-WIN32`, if you want 32-bit OpenSSL or `perl Configure VC-WIN64A` if you want 64-bit OpenSSL
6. Enter `nmake`
7. Enter `nmake test`
8. Enter `nmake install`

[EDIT, unless you change the target directory in the configuration, nmake install needs administrator privileges. So the VC command prompt must be started as administrator for this final step]

If anything goes wrong at any stage, check the [INSTALL](https://github.com/openssl/openssl/blob/OpenSSL_1_1_0-stable/INSTALL) file and the [NOTES.WIN](https://github.com/openssl/openssl/blob/OpenSSL_1_1_0-stable/NOTES.WIN) file.

Comment: There are exist followed post - http://developer.covenanteyes.com/building-openssl-for-visual-studio/   Where dont recomend to use nasm: "Don’t try to use NASM like the Windows installation instructions mention. It’s not necessary for Visual Studio builds. (It only supports 32-bit anyway.)". At least I found that the nams now have 2 version - for 32-bit and for 64-bit. So I will try it, may be it realy works for x64.

Comment: @AeroSun - Stop listening to those junk blogs. The crap that grows out of those blogs is one of the reasons there is so much bad and incorrect information on the web about OpenSSL. As soon as some idiot has a thought, it goes into a tweet or a blog. Follow the Windows README or INSTALL provided by the OpenSSL devs. Or better, listen to Matt. He's an OpenSSL dev.

Comment: @MattCaswell Just FYI, yes, this works fine in VS 2017. Nice job guys.

Comment: I had to use vcvarsall.bat before nmake to be able to compile with visual studio: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f2ccy3wt.aspx

Comment: Yes, vcvarsall.bat also works if you use a normal command prompt and not a developer command prompt.

Comment: @MattCaswell Is this the correct way to proceed for older versions of VS such as MSVC9 (2008)? I don't have nmake in my path even if I run the correct vsvars32.bit in my environment. Any tips?

Comment: That's quite an old version of MSVC, that I don't have access to. In principle the concept for building is the same for all versions of MSVC - but I can't really comment on specific problems with that version. Is there no developer command prompt available in that version?

Comment: @MattCaswell to obtain DEBUG builds, would I just run `perl Configure debug-VC-WIN32` (or `debug-VC-WIN64A`)?  And to obtain static libraries (so I do not have to include VC runtime libraries as DLLs), would I add `-static` as the first parameter to Configure?  Its very unclear how to do static builds or debug builds on Windows from the current Wiki, included docs or blogs (the latter often refer to running `ms/nt.mak`, but those makefiles no longer exist).

Comment: @MikeOnline, this is covered in the INSTALL file. Use the "--debug" option for debug builds. Use the "no-shared" option for static builds. e.g. `perl Configure --debug VC-WIN32 no-shared`

Comment: If you get a message about missing dmake.exe, run `ppm install dmake`

Comment: @MattCaswell After building and using library 1.1.1, after successfull build of my project, at start of runtime, get msvcrt90.dll not found, but in version 1.0.2 didn't get this error. Do you have any idea?

Comment: Hmm..not sure. I'd suggest posting that as a separate question, or asking on the openssl-users@openssl.org email list (see https://www.openssl.org/community/mailinglists.html)

Comment: At the time of this comment, ActivePerl has errors - missing win32 console PM. Use Strawberry Perl.

Comment: @MattCaswell thanks, this worked nicely. However, I don't see a .pc pkg-config file for OpenSSL. any ideas on where I can find such ?

Comment: On Unix/Linux there is an openssl.pc, libssl.pc and libcrypto.pc in install-dir/lib/pkgconfig. I don't believe they get created for Windows builds.

Comment: I just spent hours on unsuccessfully trying to do this with ActiveState Perl (V5.28) as recommended in the readme file of opensssl. I failed, and then found this information: https://github.com/openssl/openssl/issues/12068. The recommendation to use Strawberry Perl makes a lot of sense. With that, the configuration worked right out of the box

Comment: Not that anyone will necessarily see this, but my company carries an extended support contract with OpenSSL. We're building 1.0.2y, and these instructions do NOT work with Visual Studio 2015u3 x86 command prompt. The execution error is at the initial `nmake`, and complains that line 243 of Makefile has in invalid `{` in a macro name. Examination reveals the optional fipsdir configuration (and others later) using `${name}` for macro wrappers, where everything else is using `$(name)`. It seems nmake no likey the former. Bummer. I was really hoping to simplify my build with your instructions.

Comment: @WhozCraig these are build instructions for OpenSSL 1.1.0+. The  build system is completely different for 1.0.2 - so these instructions won't work there.

Comment: Try as I might I saw no such restriction in the question or your answer until you last comment. Thus why I held such misplaced hope.

Comment: @WhozCraig I've edited my answer to make this clear.

Comment: @MattCaswell Thanks. I'll be *such* a happy man when I have a FIPS-validated anything-beyond-1.0.2, ideally building off cmake, so we can put all this madness behind us.

Comment: I can confirm this works for Visual Studio 2022, but with a major hitch: **The correct command line to use is `x64 Native Tools Command Prompt for VS 2022`**, if you intend to build for 64-bit applications. There's a different command line called `Developer Command Prompt for VS 2022` which **will not work**, as it will cause a desync between the expected target machine types (it'll try to build one part for x86 and another for x64) and fail at the `nmake` stage.

Answer (score 3):

Modified version of The Quantum Physicist python script

It can compile OpenSSL 1.0.x or OpenSSL 1.1.x

It can compile with multiple version of Visual Studio 2017/2019 included.

1) Create the file: CompileOpenSSL.py

```
import os
import os.path
from subprocess import call
import shutil
import sys
import re
import argparse

# args
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("-f", "--filename", help="First argument must be the tar.gz file of OpenSSL source", required=True)
parser.add_argument("-a", "--arch", help="Second argument must be x86 or amd64", required=True)
parser.add_argument("-v", "--vs_version", help="Visual Studio version (eg:90, 140, 150)", required=True)
parser.set_defaults(writeVersionInfos=False)
args = parser.parse_args()

compile_flags = "-no-asm"
#compile_flags = "-no-asm -no-shared"

openssl_32_flag = "VC-WIN32"
openssl_64_flag = "VC-WIN64A"

working_dir = os.getcwd()

dirname  = args.filename.replace(".tar.gz","")

src_32_suffix = "_" + "vs" + args.vs_version + "_32"
src_64_suffix = "_" + "vs" + args.vs_version + "_64"

vs_tools_env_var = "VS" + args.vs_version + "COMNTOOLS"


if args.arch != "x86" and args.arch != "amd64":
    print("Second argument must be x86 or amd64")
    exit(1)


if not bool(re.match("(openssl-){1}(\d)+(.)(\d)+(.)(\d)+(\w)+(.tar.gz)",args.filename)):
    print("The file given doesn't seem to be an openssl source file. It must be in the form: openssl-x.y.zw.tar.gz")
    exit(1)


call("7z x -y " + args.filename) #extract the .gz file

dirname_src_32 = dirname + src_32_suffix
dirname_src_64 = dirname + src_64_suffix
dirname_bin_32 = dirname + src_32_suffix + "_build"
dirname_bin_64 = dirname + src_64_suffix + "_build"

openssl_tar_file = args.filename[0:-3]

if args.arch == "x86":

#delete previous directories
    shutil.rmtree(os.getcwd()+'/'+dirname, ignore_errors=True)
    shutil.rmtree(os.getcwd()+'/'+dirname_src_32, ignore_errors=True)

#extract tar file for 32

    call("7z x -y " + openssl_tar_file)
    os.rename(dirname, dirname_src_32)

#Compile 32
    os.chdir(dirname_src_32)

    print("perl Configure " + openssl_32_flag + " --prefix=" + os.path.join(working_dir,dirname_bin_32) + " " + compile_flags)
    call("perl Configure " + openssl_32_flag + " --prefix=" + os.path.join(working_dir,dirname_bin_32) + " " + compile_flags,shell=True)

    if( os.path.exists("ms/do_ms.bat") ):
        call("ms\do_ms.bat",shell=True)
        print(os.getcwd())
        call("nmake -f ms/ntdll.mak",shell=True)
        call("nmake -f ms/ntdll.mak install",shell=True)
    else:
        call("nmake",shell=True)
        call("nmake test",shell=True)
        call("nmake install",shell=True)

    print("32-bit compilation complete.")

#Go back to base dir
os.chdir(working_dir)
################

if args.arch == "amd64":

#delete previous directories
    shutil.rmtree(os.getcwd()+'/'+dirname, ignore_errors=True)
    shutil.rmtree(os.getcwd()+'/'+dirname_src_64, ignore_errors=True)


#extract for 64
    call("7z x -y " + openssl_tar_file)
    os.rename(dirname, dirname_src_64)

#Compile 64
    os.chdir(dirname_src_64)

    call("perl Configure " + openssl_64_flag + " --prefix=" + os.path.join(working_dir,dirname_bin_64) + " " + compile_flags,shell=True)
    if( os.path.exists("ms\do_ms.bat") ):
        call("ms\do_win64a.bat",shell=True)
        call("nmake -f ms/ntdll.mak",shell=True)
        call("nmake -f ms/ntdll.mak install",shell=True)
    else:
        call("nmake",shell=True)
        call("nmake test",shell=True)
        call("nmake install",shell=True)

    print("64-bit compilation complete.")

#Go back to base dir
os.chdir(working_dir)
################

os.remove(openssl_tar_file)
```

2) Create the file: CompileOpenSSL_vs.cmd

```
ECHO  --------------------------------------
ECHO Require Python, 7Zip, PERL and NASM in PATH
ECHO  --------------------------------------

Rem ------------------------------------------------------
Rem TO CONFIGURE -----------------------------------------
Rem ------------------------------------------------------

Rem SET YOUR LOCAL PATHS-----------------------------------------
SET PATH=C:\Program Files (x86)\7-Zip;C:\Perl64\bin;M:\Backup\Coders\_tools\7-Zip\;%PATH% 

Rem SET YOUR OPENSSL ARCHIVE-----------------------------------------
REM SET FILENAME=openssl-1.0.2r.tar.gz 
SET FILENAME=openssl-1.1.1b.tar.gz

Rem SET THE VERSION OF YOUR VISUAL STUDIO-----------------------------------------
SET VSVERSION=%1


Rem ------------------------------------------------------
Rem COMPILATION LAUNCH -----------------------------------
Rem ------------------------------------------------------

Rem UTILS PATH-----
SET VSCOMNTOOLSNAME=VS%VSVERSION%COMNTOOLS

Rem Pick the good path for Visual Studio-----------------------------------------
IF %VSVERSION% GEQ 150 (
    Echo DO NOT FORGET TO ADD A SYSTEM VARIABLE %VSCOMNTOOLSNAME% - like: "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\Common7\Tools\"
    SET VCVARPATH="%%%VSCOMNTOOLSNAME%%%..\..\VC\Auxiliary\Build\vcvarsall.bat"
) ELSE (
    SET VCVARPATH="%%%VSCOMNTOOLSNAME%%%..\..\VC\vcvarsall.bat"
)

Rem Set env -----------------------------------------
@pushd "%~dp0"
call %VCVARPATH% %2
@popd

Rem ------------------------------------------------------
Rem TEST APP EXIST -----------------------------------
Rem ------------------------------------------------------

where /q 7z.exe
IF ERRORLEVEL 1 (
    ECHO The application "7z.exe" is missing. Ensure to add/install it to the PATH in beginning of this script, check SET PATH
    PAUSE
    EXIT /B
)

where /q perl.exe
IF ERRORLEVEL 1 (
    ECHO The application "perl.exe" is missing. Ensure to add/install it to the PATH in beginning of this script, check SET PATH
    PAUSE
    EXIT /B
)

where /q nmake.exe
IF ERRORLEVEL 1 (
    ECHO The application "nmake.exe" is missing. Ensure to add/install it to the PATH in beginning of this script, check SET PATH
    PAUSE
    EXIT /B
)

where /q py.exe
IF ERRORLEVEL 1 (
    ECHO The application "py.exe" [shortcut of python] is missing. Ensure to add/install it to the PATH in beginning of this script, check SET PATH
    PAUSE
    EXIT /B
)

Rem Launch compilation -----------------------------------------

py CompileOpenSSL.py -f %FILENAME% -a %2 -v %VSVERSION%


PAUSE
```

3) Launch compilation from command line (Outside Visual Studio)
eg:

```
CompileOpenSSL_vs.cmd 150 x86
CompileOpenSSL_vs.cmd 150 amd64

CompileOpenSSL_vs.cmd 90 x86
```

Answer (score 1):

For OpenSSL 1.0.2, I wrote a Python script that does the building for me. I have this habit of making these scripts, as I don't like to reinvent the wheel everytime I need to build something.

The script is made for OpenSSL 1.0.2. Probably the changes are minimal for OpenSSL 1.1.0.

Here's the script:

```
import os
from subprocess import call
import sys
import re

vs_version = "140"
compile_flags = "-no-asm -no-shared"


openssl_32_flag = "VC-WIN32"
openssl_64_flag = "VC-WIN64A"

src_32_suffix = "_" + "vs" + vs_version + "_32"
src_64_suffix = "_" + "vs" + vs_version + "_64"

vs_tools_env_var = "VS" + vs_version + "COMNTOOLS"

if len(sys.argv) < 2:
    print("First argument must be the tar.gz file of OpenSSL source")
    exit(1)

if len(sys.argv) < 3:
    print("Second argument must be 32 or 64")
    exit(1)

filename = sys.argv[1]
dirname  = filename.replace(".tar.gz","")
working_dir = os.getcwd()
arch = sys.argv[2]

if arch != "32" and arch != "64":
    print("Second argument must be 32 or 64")
    exit(1)


if not bool(re.match("(openssl-){1}(\d)+(.)(\d)+(.)(\d)+(\w)+(.tar.gz)",filename)):
    print("The file given doesn't seem to be an openssl source file. It must be in the form: openssl-x.y.zw.tar.gz")
    exit(1)


call("7z x " + filename) #extract the .gz file

dirname_src_32 = dirname + src_32_suffix
dirname_src_64 = dirname + src_64_suffix
dirname_bin_32 = dirname + src_32_suffix + "_build"
dirname_bin_64 = dirname + src_64_suffix + "_build"

openssl_tar_file = filename[0:-3]

if arch == "32":
#extract tar file for 32
    call("7z x " + openssl_tar_file)
    os.rename(dirname, dirname_src_32)

#Compile 32
    os.chdir(dirname_src_32)

    call("perl Configure " + openssl_32_flag + " --prefix=" + os.path.join(working_dir,dirname_bin_32) + " " + compile_flags,shell=True)
    call(r"ms\do_ms.bat",shell=True)
    call(r"nmake -f ms\nt.mak",shell=True)
    call(r"nmake -f ms\nt.mak instalL",shell=True)

    print("32-bit compilation complete.")

#Go back to base dir
os.chdir(working_dir)
################

if arch == "64":
#extract for 64
    call("7z x " + openssl_tar_file)
    os.rename(dirname, dirname_src_64)

#Compile 64
    os.chdir(dirname_src_64)

    call("perl Configure " + openssl_64_flag + " --prefix=" + os.path.join(working_dir,dirname_bin_64) + " " + compile_flags,shell=True)
    call(r"ms\do_ms.bat",shell=True)
    call(r"nmake -f ms\nt.mak",shell=True)
    call(r"nmake -f ms\nt.mak instalL",shell=True)

    print("64-bit compilation complete.")

#Go back to base dir
os.chdir(working_dir)
################

os.remove(openssl_tar_file)
```

**Option 1**: Save the script to `CompileOpenSSL.py`, and download the OpenSSL source file that is expected to have the name format `openssl-1.X.Y.tar.gz`. Now assuming that 7zip and perl are accessible from the global scope on your command prompt and you have the correct MSVC variables loaded (with e.g. `vsvars32.bat`, or starting the right terminal), run the following:

```
python CompileOpenSSL.py openssl-1.X.Y.tar.gz 32
```

If you're using MSVC 32-bit, or

```
python CompileOpenSSL.py openssl-1.X.Y.tar.gz 64
```

for MSVC 64-bit.

**Option 2**: Do what the script does manually. The script simply extracts the archive, configures the sources and runs `do_ms.bat` then `nmake`. Follow the source and it'll work.

Good luck!

Comment: The build procedure has changed significantly between OpenSSL 1.0.2 and OpenSSL 1.1.0

Comment: I used newest sources - there are no following files: ms\do_ms.bat, ms\nt.mak

Comment: @AeroSun Like the guy's  said, OpenSSL 1.1.0 is different. The instructions I gave are for OpenSSL 1.0.2.

Answer (score 1):

1. go into ssl directory using visual studio cmd and add perl and nasm to system path then type:
2. `perl Configure --openssldir=D:OpenSSLdirectory VC-WIN32`
3. `ms\do_ms.bat`
4. `nmake -f ms\ntdll.mak`
5. `nmake -f ms\ntdll.mak install`
6. ( enjoy. )