# Is there an OpenSSL for windows?

Tags: windows, openssl

I'm trying to generate OpenSSL certificates on Windows OS. But I find most of the commands related to OpenSSL are for *nix OS.

Is there an OpenSSL for Windows OS? If yes, from where can I get it? Is this official OpenSSL build for Windows?

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50625283/how-to-install-openssl-in-windows-10

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes. You can do one of two things:

1. Build it yourself

   You'll need a build environment (either Visual Studio or msys2 based), and a few other pre-requisites. Download the source from here:

   https://www.openssl.org/source/

   And (assuming you downloaded the 1.1.0 version), read the INSTALL notes here:

   https://github.com/openssl/openssl/blob/OpenSSL_1_1_0-stable/INSTALL

   There are also some Windows specific notes here:

   https://github.com/openssl/openssl/blob/OpenSSL_1_1_0-stable/NOTES.WIN
2. Download a pre-compiled version

   The OpenSSL project doesn't distribute pre-compiled binaries, but they do maintain a list of third-party provided binaries. The list is here:

   https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Binaries

Comment: Can you also explain the process of building it in Windows?

Comment: The details are all in the INSTALL and NOTES.WIN files. For an overview see my answer on another question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45494630/how-to-build-openssl-on-windows-with-visual-studio-2017/45495686#45495686

Answer (score 5):

Search `openssl shining light production` in google and download from the first link

Comment: Search engine results are evolving every day. Better to put the direct link here !!

Comment: https://slproweb.com/products/Win32OpenSSL.html for who needs

Answer (score 3):

If you're using Chocolatey, you can also install with

```
choco install openssl
```

More details in [here](https://community.chocolatey.org/packages/openssl) and for me it also installed some other stuff, like VC Redist:

```
Installed:
 - kb2919355 v1.0.20160915
 - kb3033929 v1.0.5
 - kb2999226 v1.0.20181019
 - openssl v1.1.1.1900
 - vcredist2015 v14.0.24215.20170201
 - kb2919442 v1.0.20160915
 - vcredist140 v14.34.31931
 - kb3035131 v1.0.3
 - chocolatey-windowsupdate.extension v1.0.5

Packages requiring reboot:
 - vcredist140 (exit code 3010)
```

This was done on Windows 10.

Answer (score 1):

I am using this version https://slproweb.com/products/Win32OpenSSL.html and install it with

### Essentials

```
winget install -e ShiningLight.OpenSSL.Light
```

### Full

```
winget install -e ShiningLight.OpenSSL
```

Comment: sadly this fail (for me, today) with `404 not found`

Comment: you are right, the link to the download file seems to be broken

Answer (score 0):

Both Cygwin and MSYS distribute pre-compiled openssl binaries, which I use everyday.

If you don't like a *nix like style, please refer this official page for standalone distrbutions.

https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Binaries

Disclaim: I have not tested the software listed on the page.