# How to connect to secure web site (https:)?

Tags: ssl, https, openssl

I am trying to connect to a secure (https:) website and perform write/read operations. I tried to find a simple example for this using OpenSSL but all the examples seemed to be for earlier versions and the doc varied widely. I salvaged what I could, made some mods and created a simple "Hello, World" SSL program (below). It mostly works but fails on SSL_write().  The error is SSL_ERROR_SSL.

```
//  client.c - SSL client program
// Uses OpenSSL v1.1.1i for Win32

#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include "openssl/ssl.h"    // openSSL includes
#include "client.h"

// LINK TO THESE LIBRARIES
#pragma comment( lib, "libssl.lib" )
#pragma comment( lib, "Ws2_32.lib" )

//@ Main program
int
main(
  int argc,     // count of args
  char **argv)      //ptr to array or arg strings
{
    #define HOSTNAME "www.fax.plus"     // secure host
    #define PORT     443                // https port
    int i,ok;
    WSADATA data;
    SSL_METHOD *method;
    SSL_CTX *ctx;
    SSL *ssl;
    SOCKET s;
    char request[1024+1];
    SSL_METHOD *TLSv1_2_client_method();    // not defined in includes!?

    i = WSAStartup( 0x002, &data );                     // start winsock
    if( i ) sslFatalExit( "on WSAStartup" );
    printf( "OK: WinSock Started.\n" );

    method = TLSv1_2_client_method();                   // get method
    ctx = SSL_CTX_new( method );                        // get ctx
    if( !ctx ) sslFatalExit( "on SSL_CTX_new" );
    printf( "OK: SSL CTX created\n" );

    ssl = SSL_new( ctx );                               // get ssl
    if( !ssl ) sslFatalExit( "on SSL_new" );
    printf( "OK: SSL ssl created.\n" );

    s = sslConnect( HOSTNAME, PORT );                   // connect to host
    if( s <= 0 ) sslFatalExit( "on sslConnect" );
    printf( "OK: Connected to %s:%u\n", HOSTNAME, PORT );

    ok = SSL_set_fd( ssl, s );                          // set ssl socket
    if( !ok ) sslFatalExit( "SSL_set_fd" );
    printf( "OK: SSL socket set.\n" );

    strncpy( request, "GET / HTTP/1.00\r\n\r\n", 1024 );
    i = SSL_write( ssl, request, strlen( request ) );   // write request to host
    if( i != 1 ) sslReportError( i, ssl );    // ALWAYS FAILS !

    // more...

    return( 0 );
}

//@ Connect to host:port
SOCKET
sslConnect(
  char *hostname,   // host name
  WORD port)        // port number
{
    int i,sd;
    struct hostent *host;
    struct sockaddr_in addr;

    host = gethostbyname( hostname );
    if( host == NULL ) {
      perror( hostname );
      return( 0 );
    }
    sd = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0 );
    ZeroMemory( &addr, sizeof(addr ) );
    addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    addr.sin_port = htons( port );
    addr.sin_addr.s_addr = *(long *)(host->h_addr);
    i = connect( sd, (struct sockaddr*)&addr, sizeof(addr));
    if( i != 0 ) {
      perror( hostname );
      return( 0 );
    }
    return( sd );
    //r Returns connected socket or 0 on error
}

//@ Report SSL error
void
sslReportError(
  int code,
  SSL *ssl)
{
    int sslerr;
    char *msg;
    sslerr = SSL_get_error( ssl, code );
    msg = sslErrorName( sslerr );
    printf( "ERROR: %s\n", msg );
    sslFatalExit( "on SSL_write" );

}

//@ Get string of ssl error code
char *
sslErrorName(
  int code) // code returned by SSL_get_error()
{
    switch( code ) {
      case SSL_ERROR_NONE:              return( "[0] SSL_ERROR_NONE" );
      case SSL_ERROR_SSL:               return( "[1] SSL_ERROR_SSL" );
      case SSL_ERROR_WANT_READ:         return( "[2] SSL_ERROR_WANT_READ" );
      case SSL_ERROR_WANT_WRITE:        return( "[4] SSL_ERROR_WANT_WRITE" );
      case SSL_ERROR_WANT_X509_LOOKUP:  return( "[4] SSL_ERROR_WANT_X509_LOOKUP" );
      case SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL:           return( "[5] SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL" );
      case SSL_ERROR_ZERO_RETURN:       return( "[6] SSL_ERROR_ZERO_RETURN" );
      case SSL_ERROR_WANT_CONNECT:      return( "[7] SSL_ERROR_WANT_CONNECT" );
      case SSL_ERROR_WANT_ACCEPT:       return( "[8] SSL_ERROR_WANT_ACCEPT" );
      //case SSL_ERROR_WANT_ASYNC:      return( "[9] SSL_ERROR_WANT_ASYNC" );
      //case SSL_ERROR_WANT_ASYNC_JOB:  return( "[10] SSL_ERROR_WANT_ASYNC_JOB" );
      //case SSL_ERROR_WANT_CLIENT_HELLO_CB:    return( "[11] SSL_ERROR_WANT_CLIENT_HELLO_CB" );
      default:              return( "ERROR_UNKNOWN" );
      //r Returns string of error code
    }
}

//@ Print msg, pause and exit
void
sslFatalExit(
  char *msg)    // msg to print
{
    printf( "FATAL ERROR: %s\n", msg );
    printf( "Press any key to exit...\n" );
    getch();
    exit( 1 );
}
```

**Program Output:**

```
OK: WinSock Started.
OK: SSL CTX created
OK: SSL ssl created.
OK: Connected to www.fax.plus:443
OK: SSL socket set.
ERROR: [1] SSL_ERROR_SSL
FATAL ERROR: on SSL_write
Press any key to exit...
```

**What I Tried and What Was Strange**

- Many samples called things like 'SSL_add_all_algorithms()' but this was not resolved in libssl.lib
- Some called SSL_init_ssl. This was resolved ok but caused 'SSL_CTX_new()' to FAIL. Some doc stated that this was unneccessay.
- ''TLSv1_2_client_method()' was resolved ok but was not included in the SSL include files, so I declared it myself.

**Does anybody have any insight into my problem, or an alternate approach?**

Comment: check if adding `lcrypto`  before `libssl` solve the issues of linking, also check if the linking is dynamic or static

Comment: Tried but same result. Library is static.

Comment: What are the libraries that you used?

Comment: I made a windows client program which works well and it required both linking with static libraries and the dll in the program's directory.

Comment: Are you calling SSL_connect somewhere?

Comment: Yes, but it fails.

Answer (score 0):

Here's some client code that should work out of the box.

```
#define _WINSOCKAPI_
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <ws2tcpip.h>
#include <mstcpip.h>
#include <openssl/ssl.h>

#pragma comment (lib, "Ws2_32")
#pragma comment (lib, "libssl")
#pragma comment (lib, "libcrypto")

int main() {
    WSADATA wsaData;
    int iResult = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wsaData);
    if (iResult != 0) {
        printf("Failed to initialize wsa");
    }

    printf("Started client\n");

    SSL_CTX* ctx;
    int server;
    SSL* ssl;
    char buf[1024];
    int bytes;

    const SSL_METHOD* method;
    method = TLS_client_method();
    ctx = SSL_CTX_new(method);
    if (ctx == NULL) {
        printf("Failed to create ssl context\n");
    }

    sockaddr_in addr;
    server = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    addr.sin_port = htons(4433);
    in_addr inaddr;
    inet_pton(AF_INET, "127.0.0.1", &inaddr);
    addr.sin_addr = inaddr;
    if (connect(server, (sockaddr*)&addr, sizeof(addr)) != 0)
    {
        printf("Failed to connect to server\n");
    }

    ssl = SSL_new(ctx);
    SSL_set_fd(ssl, server);

    if (SSL_connect(ssl) == -1) {
        printf("Failed to connect with ssl\n");
    }
    else {
        printf("Connected with %s encryption\n", SSL_get_cipher(ssl));
        const char* ClientRequest = "g/hello@hello.com/\0";
        SSL_write(ssl, ClientRequest, strlen(ClientRequest));
        bytes = SSL_read(ssl, buf, 1023);
        buf[bytes] = '\0';
        printf("Received: %s\n", buf);
        SSL_free(ssl);
    }

    closesocket(server);
    SSL_CTX_free(ctx);

    WSACleanup();
    return 0;
}
```

You need to call both connects (the one for basic sockets and the one for SSL). I think that the handshake happens in 2 calls. The basic connect makes a normal socket unencrypted handshake then you need to call SSL_connect() to make the encrypted handshake with asymmetrical encryption etc.

**EDIT**

You should probably build your own libraries as this is more safe and more customizable. I've been doing some testing with a stackoverflow answer by an OpenSSL developer ([How to build OpenSSL on Windows with Visual Studio 2017?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45494630/how-to-build-openssl-on-windows-with-visual-studio-2017)). Building your own OpenSSL libraries is easy and simple. Basically,

- Download Perl Stawberry (https://strawberryperl.com/)
- Download NASM (https://www.nasm.us/pub/nasm/releasebuilds/2.15.05/)
- Create Path Environment Variables on your machine to your NASM and Perl install
- Download OpenSSL source code (in a git command prompt on Windows type "git clone git://git.openssl.org/openssl.git" or download the source code from Github directly)
- Open a Visual Studio developer prompt (in Visual Studio click Tools > Command Line > Developer Command Prompt)
- Change directory to the OpenSSL source code
- Type in "perl Configure VC-WIN32" for dynamic compiling version (it will create dynamic libraries so you need to put these in your executable's directory in addition to linking with the static libs) or "perl Configure VC-WIN32 no-shared" for static compiling (with this you will have only the static libraries so no need to have any dll in your executable's directory)
- Lastly, type "nmake". This will start compiling OpenSSL. In the end you will have the libraries (and dll with dynamic compiling) in the OpenSSL source code root directory.

The working code for the dynamic version of OpenSSL is the following:

```
#define _WINSOCKAPI_
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <ws2tcpip.h>
#include <openssl/ssl.h>


#pragma comment (lib, "Ws2_32")
#pragma comment (lib, "libssl")

int main() {
    WSADATA wsaData;
    int iResult = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wsaData);
    if (iResult != 0) {
        std::cout << "Failed to initialize wsa" << std::endl;
    }

    printf("Started client\n");

    SSL_CTX* ctx;
    int server;
    SSL* ssl;
    char buf[1024];
    int bytes;

    const SSL_METHOD* method;
    method = TLS_client_method();
    ctx = SSL_CTX_new(method);
    if (ctx == NULL) {
        printf("Failed to create ssl context\n");
    }

    sockaddr_in addr;
    server = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    addr.sin_port = htons(443);
    in_addr inaddr;
    inet_pton(AF_INET, "172.217.13.110", &inaddr);
    addr.sin_addr = inaddr;
    if (connect(server, (sockaddr*)&addr, sizeof(addr)) != 0)
    {
        printf("Failed to connect to server\n");
    }

    ssl = SSL_new(ctx);
    SSL_set_fd(ssl, server);

    if (SSL_connect(ssl) == -1) {
        printf("Failed to connect with ssl\n");
    }
    else {
        printf("Connected with %s encryption\n", SSL_get_cipher(ssl));
        const char* ClientRequest = "GET / HTTP / 1.00\r\n\r\n\0";
        SSL_write(ssl, ClientRequest, strlen(ClientRequest));
        bytes = SSL_read(ssl, buf, 1023);
        buf[bytes] = '\0';
        printf("Received: %s\n", buf);
        SSL_free(ssl);
    }

    closesocket(server);
    SSL_CTX_free(ctx);

    WSACleanup();
    return 0;
}
```

There's no need to link with libcrypto.lib but you need to place libssl-3.dll and libcrypto-3.dll in your executable's directory. With this code and following the compilation guide up there I get the following output (the IP address is google.com):

```
Started client
Connected with TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 encryption
Received: HTTP/1.0 400 Bad Request
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Referrer-Policy: no-referrer
Content-Length: 1555
Date: Tue, 23 Feb 2021 06:59:28 GMT

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang=en>
  <meta charset=utf-8>
  <meta name=viewport content="initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width">
  <title>Error 400 (Bad Request)!!1</title>
  <style>
    *{margin:0;padding:0}html,code{font:15px/22px arial,sans-serif}html{background:#fff;color:#222;padding:15px}body{margin:7% auto 0;max-width:390px;min-height:180px;padding:30px 0 15px}* > body{background:url(//www.google.com/images/errors/robot.png) 100% 5px no-repeat;padding-right:205px}p{margin:11px 0 22px;overflow:hidden}ins{color:#777;text-decoration:none}a img{border:0}@media screen and (max-width:772px){body{background:none;margin-top:0;max-width:none;padding-right:0}}#logo{background:url(//www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_150x54dp.png) no-repeat;margin-left:-5px}@media only screen and (min-resolution:192dpi){#logo{background:
```

You see that it is connecting well sending your request and obviously google.com answers with a bad request.

The working code for static compiling is the same except you need to add these 2 lines at the top (to link with libcrypto and crypt32).

```
#pragma comment (lib, "libcrypto")
#pragma comment (lib, "crypt32")
```

With the static libs and the same code except for these 2 additional linkage, I get the same output.

Comment: Thanks for the simple and clear example. I'm still having issues: can't find inet_pton or TLS_client_method(). I'm researching these...

Comment: inet_pton is in ws2tcpip.h. While TLS_client_method() may be in a higher version of OpenSSL. As stated on https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.0/man3/TLS_client_method.html, TLS_method(), TLS_server_method(), TLS_client_method(), DTLS_method(), DTLS_server_method() and DTLS_client_method() are the version-flexible methods. All other methods only support one specific protocol version. Use the version-flexible methods instead of the version specific methods.

Comment: What libraries are you using? Did you compile your own. You may be using old precompiled libraries of the 1.0 version of OpenSSL.

Comment: Still no luck. All calls up through SSL_connect succeeded but SSL_connect returns -1. I'm using library version v1.1.1i downloaded from Shining Light. BTW, I tried the DTLS methods with no difference. Also, 'TLS_client_method' is not in the SSL include files but IS resolved: I had to declare it as an extern in my app to get rid of warnings

Comment: These libraries don't work. Try the last link here https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Binaries that is https://kb.firedaemon.com/support/solutions/articles/4000121705. This one worked for me.

Comment: With a dependency on visual studio as they say on the website.

Comment: Or compile your own.

Comment: user123, I tried the firedaemon files as you suggested, but still no luck - same error. After some digging,  I think the problem is with 'ssl = SSL_new(ctx)'. The ctx has a method table that looks credible, but the new ssl object contains a method table that is all NULL's. I'm trying to compile libssl from source but running into major hurdles.

Comment: On what system are you, did you try to follow my edit to the letter. This should work out of the box without question.

Comment: Yes, I used your edits exactly (although I used my own pton/connect because I couldn't get those to work. By my connect code works perfectly). I'm running on a Dell Optiplex Win10/64 machine

Comment: You need to use the exact code I edited. Then try it out with google.com. Then adjust the code to work with the ip address of your website. There is no reason for it to not work exactly as mentionned. Are you on visual studio? You may need to dowload the windows SDK for additionnal headers. If those that I included are not found on your system.

Comment: If the exact code I posted doesn't work on your system then find out the reason why, post any errors you get and then I may help resolving these. Editing the code with your own custom one will not make it work magically.

Comment: Also, you are working with C with Win32 code.  Win32 is C++. My advice is stop working with outdated C and switch to C++.