# Why installed libtorrent shows Import Error?

Tags: c++, python-3.x, dependency-management, libtorrent, libtorrent-rasterbar

I have built libtorrent with boost with this commands in the boost root folder :

```
bootstrap.bat
b2 --hash cxxstd=14 release
```

and after I have added **BOOST_ROOT** and **BOOST_BUILD_PATH** to **PATH** variable.

I also have downloaded OpenSSL and build it then have copied to **Visual studio 15 2017** compiler include and libs folder repectively.

Next in the libtorrent root folder I have run this commands:

```
b2 variant=release link=shared
b2 install --prefix=build
```

The build was successful and libtorrent c++ library has created.

and after that I have run these commands :

```
py setup.py build
py setup.py install
```

They executed with no errors and libtorrent installed in my python
**libs/site-packages** folder. But when I import it this error shows:

Python Import Error
[[image]]

What build steps might I have done wrong?

Os : Windows 10 x64

Python : 3.9.5 x64

Libtorrent : 2.0.5

Boost : 1.78.0

I have followed from the libtorrent docs :
https://libtorrent.org/building.html
and
https://www.libtorrent.org/python_binding.html

Comment: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: You are actually sharing very little info on how you (tried to) install libtorrent, and how you (try to) use it.  Can you [edit] the question, and add this info ?

Comment: @Luuk I edited the post, sorry for that. But what do you think about that?

Comment: Looking much better. building fails here because it is missing the headers from openssl, and I do not feel like searching how/where to get them.... 

Comment: @Luuk fogot to write that I have downloaded and built openssl and copy them to visual studio libs and includes folder, do you mean openssl is missed from python libs folder?

Comment: I clearly tell you that I got no error in building for missing any libraries or file. If it is possible write down how you have built it?

Comment: I started with `git clone --recurse-submodules https://github.com/arvidn/libtorrent.git`, and followed the rest of the instructions (on [gitub](https://github.com/arvidn/libtorrent/blob/master/docs/building.rst#downloading-and-building)). I also had to do an install of Boost

Comment: The github instructions is the same as libtorrent docs. I have done the same, but for checking I ask you that , did you build boost shared or static in both library type and runtime linking or not, please write the exact command of how you build boost and write the version of library both libtorrent and boost you used?). Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer.

While building libtorrent python binding 2 factors are important:

1- openSSL version
2- linking type

1. python comes with openssl v.1.1 (or similar based on python version) , if building python binding with openssl v.1.1 (which is the latest version while I am writing) one dependency solved otherwise, if using openssl v.3 for building 2 dependency must add to python which they are:

```
// 32 or 64 bits library based on openssl build

libssl-3-x64.dll
libcrypto-3-x64.dll
```

2 ) in the time of building python binding 2 commands can be use:

a ) simple with default parameters :

```
py setup.py build
py setup.py install
```

In this case in default libtorrent and boost-python linking **static**.

b ) complex one with more control (I think) :

```
py setup.py build_ext --b2-args="VARS" install
```

In the VARS place we can write boost build options but these are the one we want:

```
libtorrent-link=TYPE  boost-link= TYPE
```

**TYPE** can be **static** or **shared** but anyone that sets **shared** , it becomes dependency. two files which is in need are :

```
// 32 and 64 bits file may have different name
// files can have different names but they are similar to below

torrent-rastarbar.dll
boost_python(PYTHON-VERSION)(SOME-INFO).dll
```

**boost python** can be find in the boost root directory in the **stage/lib** .

**pleae note that you must build boost and libtorrent SHARED for this solution.**

Conclusion :

as mentioned above these dependency must add to based on the build setting you did:

1 - OpenSSL libraries
2 - Boost python
3 - libtorrent libraries

There is an optional file that mentioned in some forums and discussion **msvcr90.dll** which does not effect on my project but good to point.

Put those files to a directory which can be find by python interpreter or put in project your folder and add this piece of code **before imporing libtorrent**  :

```
import os

current_path = os.path.abspath(".")

# do not pass relative path like ".", pass full path

os.add_dll_directory(current_path)
```

Sorry for any poor english. :)

Answer (score 0):

What did I do ?

Basically following: https://github.com/arvidn/libtorrent/blob/master/docs/building.rst#downloading-and-building

Unzipping `boost_1_78_0.zip` into D:\boost_1_78_0, and running:

```
set BOOST_ROOT=D:\boost_1_78_0
set BOOST_BUILD_PATH=%BOOST_ROOT%\tools\build
(cd %BOOST_ROOT% && .\bootstrap.bat)
echo using msvc ; >>%HOMEDRIVE%%HOMEPATH%\user-config.jam
%BOOST_ROOT%\b2.exe --hash release
```

After this i got:

> The Boost C++ Libraries were successfully built!
>
> The following directory should be added to compiler include paths:
>
> ```
> D:\boost_1_78_0
> ```
>
> The following directory should be added to linker library paths:
>
> ```
> D:\boost_1_78_0\stage\lib
> ```

I think this is where i started to fail, I did not read this the first time, and now I am asking meself where/how should the "compiler include paths" and "linker library paths" be set .?

When trying to compile `libtorrent`, using the command-line you provided (`b2 msvc-14.2 variant=release link=static runtime-link=static debug-symbols=on`), i got:

```
CXXFLAGS =
LDFLAGS =
OS = NT
building boost from source directory:  D:/boost_1_78_0
Performing configuration checks

    - default address-model    : 64-bit (cached) [1]
    - default architecture     : x86 (cached) [1]

[1] msvc-14.2
...patience...
...patience...
...patience...
...found 3888 targets...
...updating 78 targets...
compile-c-c++ bin\msvc-14.2\release\cxxstd-14-iso\debug-symbols-on\link-static\runtime-link-static\threading-multi\src\hasher.obj
hasher.cpp
D:\TEMP\libtorrent\libtorrent\include\libtorrent/hasher.hpp(66): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'openssl/sha.h': No such file or directory

    call "bin\standalone\msvc\msvc-14.2\msvc-setup.bat"  >nul
 cl /Zm800 -nologo "src\hasher.cpp" -c -Fo"bin\msvc-14.2\release\cxxstd-14-iso\debug-symbols-on\link-static\runtime-link-static\threading-multi\src\hasher.obj"     -TP /bigobj /wd4251 /wd4268 /wd4275 /wd4373 /wd4503 /wd4675 /EHs /std:c++14 /GR /Zc:throwingNew /O2 /Z7 /Ob2 /W4 /MT /Zc:forScope /Zc:wchar_t /Zc:inline /Gw /favor:blend -DBOOST_ALL_NO_LIB -DBOOST_ASIO_ENABLE_CANCELIO -DBOOST_ASIO_HAS_STD_CHRONO -DBOOST_ASIO_NO_DEPRECATED -DBOOST_MULTI_INDEX_DISABLE_SERIALIZATION -DBOOST_NO_DEPRECATED -DBOOST_SYSTEM_NO_DEPRECATED -DBOOST_SYSTEM_STATIC_LINK=1 -DNDEBUG -DOPENSSL_NO_SSL2 -DTORRENT_BUILDING_LIBRARY -DTORRENT_SSL_PEERS -DTORRENT_USE_I2P=1 -DTORRENT_USE_LIBCRYPTO -DTORRENT_USE_OPENSSL -DWIN32 -DWIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN -D_CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_SCL_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE -D_WIN32 -D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0600 -D__USE_W32_SOCKETS "-ID:\boost_1_78_0" "-Ideps\try_signal" "-Iinclude" "-Iinclude\libtorrent" 

...failed compile-c-c++ bin\msvc-14.2\release\cxxstd-14-iso\debug-symbols-on\link-static\runtime-link-static\threading-multi\src\hasher.obj...
compile-c-c++ bin\msvc-14.2\release\cxxstd-14-iso\debug-symbols-on\link-static\runtime-link-static\threading-multi\src\merkle.obj
merkle.cpp
D:\TEMP\libtorrent\libtorrent\include\libtorrent/hasher.hpp(66): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'openssl/sha.h': No such file or directory
..... (rest of logging removed)
```

Comment: the command I provided is the same as docs. The error you got is from lack of openssl library which I installed and copied its files to place that can be find by visual studio for build. Please check that and run again and see python binding works or not. Thank you!

Comment: I have not clue how to do "... copied its files to place that can be find ..." correctly...

Comment: At the bottom of libtorrent docs for building there is a instruction for building OpenSSL on windows as well. But it is for visual studio 2003, therefor I googled for another way and found this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45494630/how-to-build-openssl-on-windows-with-visual-studio-2017   with some info from main docs and this link I installed that. As python error says it lacks something, Can you finding out what they are?